# cant able to launch instance from custom ubuntu image in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-18.04

I have launched EC2 instance (T2.Medium) from Ubuntu-18 LTS on AWS. Then i have installed NICE DCV server on ubuntu machine, and installed wine6.0, winetricks to run one windows based application. Its graphic user interface level in ubuntu. Everything working fine once installed all the things. But problem comes, when i create own image from this ubuntu instance and tried to launch new instance from this custom image, I can't able to SSH to newly launched ubuntu instance. I have tried to create image by below methods

1. I just create image from running instance with no reboot option
2. I just stopped ubuntu instance, then i create image

However, i cant able to SSH to ubuntu machine. I just had a look at the AWS console, there instance status checks failed. Then i check the instance screen shot from aws console. It seems working fine.
[image]
But why i cant able to SSH to that machine. I double checked the security group, Port SSH opened.
Can any one advice on this?

Comment: is this wrong question?

Answer (score 0):

From these answers on StackExchange there is an issue with `ifupdown`
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1047671/ami-based-on-ubuntu-18-04-aws-image-does-not-have-network-interface
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1005390/why-did-ubuntu-change-the-network-configuration

Removing it (`apt purge ifupdown`) before image creation should solve the problem.